# Emulating a USB hub with STM32

Tags: stm32

I am currently working with an STM32 development board and working with USB device library (USBD). I am currently attempting to emulate various devices to learn more about how the protocols work and have started working trying to emulator a USB Hub. I've gotten to the point that the board is recognised as a hub and is making the relevant requests, but for some reason it will not accept SetAddress commands aside from the one that sets the original address when the device connects to the host. Is there something I am missing about why I am not receiving the SetAddress packets and what I can do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, usual USB controllers cannot emulate USB HUBs. Without SetAddress, they're not sending/receiving anything apart from the control endpoint, after SetAddress they receive on one address only and ignore everything else. Even worse, it's usually not possible to change the address without an USB reset.
The STM32 is definitely not capable of emulating HUBs, but there might be other micros out there with more flexible USB controllers.